# Cancelling non-immigrant B visa without going to Thailand

Tags: visa, employment, thailand, singapore

I am from India. I applied for a non-immigrant B visa from VFS. It took 2 days and the visa was approved. The next day I got better opportunities (which will help me in my growth and carrier) from another country, and I don't want to go to Thailand now. Now, do I need to revoke the NON-B employment visa of Thailand, to work in another country?

If yes, then what would be the process of that and how much time does it take? And will it affect me to work in another country?

NOTE: I still didn't join the Thai company now and didn't go to Thailand using that visa.

Answer (score 7):

What you have is a non-immigrant visa that allows you to enter Thailand. If you do not use it, it simply expires.

A non-immigrant B visa is not an "employment visa". It is a visa that allows you to enter Thailand sponsored by a company. If you had taken the job, then upon your arrival in Thailand, you would have been required to apply for a work permit before you could start work.

To answer the question, you do not need to do anything - your visa (which is simply permission to enter the country and stay for 90 days) will expire after the "must enter by" date written on the visa.

Comment: Thanks scott, for the quick reply. I forgot to mention that the new job that I got is from Singapore. Its EP has been approved. So while entering Singapore, if Singapore officials will see that I already have NON-immigrant Category B (employment) visa (that too single entry), then will they allow me to work in SG or there will be any problem since I have Thai NON-B visa? I understand that you mentioned, that its just a visa which allows me to stay there for 90 days, but I am just confirming cause its related to my JOB  and I am a bit worried  :(

Comment: People have visas for multiple countries. I think you’re worrying about something that isn’t a problem. Why would SG care about a visa to TH?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Scott. Actually, this is my first-time international job. So I have less information about it. Again thanks a lot :)